# Load hidden div after event (loading files)

Tags: javascript, css, html, dom

I want to show some divs (tittletextbox1, tittletextbox2, textbox1 and textbox2) after loading 2 files using the input `fileInput`.

But I don't know how to hide the divs and display the divs  once the files are fully loaded.

```
<body>
    <input id="fileInput" placeholder=":input" type="file" size="50" onchange="processFiles(this.files)" multiple>
    <div id="fileOutput">
        <h2><center>DASHBOARD</center></h2>
        <div>
            <div id="tittletextbox1"><img src="images/computer.png" style="vertical-align: middle;"> Basics</div>
            <div id="tittletextbox2"><img src="images/network.png" style="vertical-align: middle;"> Networking</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="textbox1"></div>
            <div id="textbox2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please post your JavaScript and CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd give them all a class like `.hidden-div` that is `display: none;`

then on load you could just

```
$('.hidden-div').removeClass('hidden-div');
```

Comment: You absolutely, positively **do not** need jquery, just to remove a class from an element.  You can use a [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and the Element's own [classlist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to do this.

Comment: considering the quality of the question asked it seemed like a safe bet. I'll add the pure js version just in case but I'm not even positive I've answered the question.